# Error trying to create a Wordpress database table

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, mariadb

I am creating a plugin for Wordpress.
I'm trying to create a new table to insert inside the Wordpress database, but i keep getting this error and I can't understand well the reason.

"have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'wp_gdax_account_info' at line 1"

Is there a mistake in my code? Does someone know how to solve it?
Thank you in advance.

```
function jal_install(){ //create table
  global $wpdb;
  global $table_prefix;
     $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'gdax_account_info';
     $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
     if ($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE '.$table_name) != $table_name) {
     $sql = "CREATE TABLE". $table_name ."( 
         id INTEGER (10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         chiave VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
         email VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
         secret VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
         pass VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL, 
         PRIMARY KEY  (id)
         );".$charset_collate.";";
     require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
     dbDelta ($sql);
     echo "$wpdb->last_error";
     add_option("gdax-account-info", "1.0");
    }
}
```

Comment: should `TABLE". $table_name` be `TABLE ". $table_name` ?

Comment: yes i'm really thankful. I still don't know well how to use sql and I didn't know the sytnax require a space. Thank you very much